# Installing Shoes on Ubuntu 12.04: cannot find rubygems.rb

Tags: ruby, installation, shoes

I'm trying to install Shoes on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and currently have Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 installed, with 1.9.3 as the default. I tried several different methods, running several different scripts, but nothing seems to be successful. I haven't gotten any error messages; The scripts just install a lot of libraries and then seem to build Shoes, and, though I now have a `shoes` directory full of files, when I try to execute `/dist/shoes` I get this error:

```
me@me-Studio-1735:~/shoes$ ./dist/shoes
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
  from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
uninitialized constant Encoding::UTF_7
```

These are the the steps I've taken, in order:

1. I downloaded the Shoes3 .run file from the official [website](http://shoesrb.com/downloads), but when I tried to execute it, I get this output:

   ```
   Verifying archive integrity... All good.
   Uncompressing Shoes..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
   ./shoes-3.1.0.run: 1: eval: ./shoes: not found
   ```
2. I then attempted to follow [the instructions for installing on Ubuntu](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/wiki/Building-Shoes-on-Linux); I ran the script they linked to, which took about 20 minutes, but afterwards I couldn't find the `red-shoes` directory: It didn't exist. All I got to show for it was a `/tmp/shoes_build/` directory with a "chruby  opt  ruby-1.9.3-p392  ruby-build" directory listing.
3. Then I tried running the script from that same website listed directly on the site, not linked to. No Shoes. Lots of things were installed, but when I tried to execute `/dist/shoes`, I got the same error.
4. Finally, I tried executing the commands listed on the [Spiral of Hope](http://spiralofhope.com/shoes.html) site listed under 'SUCCESS: Ubuntu?'. Again, it runs and installs lots of libraries, but Shoes isn't functional. It is neither a recognized command when typing `shoes`, nor can I execute anything successfully.

I don't know what else to do. I'm no Linux buff, I just have a knowledge of basic Bash commands, and I recently installed Ubuntu, so I haven't done any weird custom installs or anything. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to do it right?